# Get the last children from database

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

My situation:

```
Table A
(
ID
Parent_Id
TimeStamp
)
```

The root has Parent_Id null and children has Id of its father.

I simple want to get all LAST children of every Table A.
Father and Children I don't want. (except last one).

Is it possible to build a SQL to get this?

PS: I'm on sql anywhere 11. Maybe an ansi sql can solve this, i'm not sure.

EDIT: (edited to give additional details)
I don't want the last children from an element.

Example:

Id 1
Parent NULL

Id 2
Parent 1

Id 3 (the last child)
Parent 1

Id 4
Parent NULL

Id 5 (the last child)
parent 4

I want to get:
Id 3
Id 5

Comment: Please, review your answer because i gave additional details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using stored function

```
create function LastChild(in parent integer)
returns integer
begin
    declare res integer;  
    select top 1 id into res from TableA where parent_id = parent order by timeCol desc;
    return res;
end
```

select

```
select Id, lastchild(id) from TAbleA where parent_id is null
```

I'll work on another solution without stored function.

EDIT: without stored function:

```
select Id, (select top 1 id from TableA childs where parent_id = TableA.id order by timeCol desc) from TableA where parent_id = 0
```

Comment: Yes! that function returned exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again, sql version without function was more appropriated for me.

Answer (score 2):

If by "last children" you mean items that themselves have no children (and often referred to as leaf-level items), something like this should do:

```
SELECT ID
 from A
 where ID not in (select Parent_Id from A)
```

The correlated subquery version is a bit tricker to understand, but would work faster on large tables:

```
SELECT ID
 from A OuterReference
 where not exists (select 1 from A where Parenti_ID = OuterReference.ID)
```

("OuterReference" is an alias for table A)

I use SQL Server, but this is pretty basic syntax and should work for you with minimal modification.

Comment: (Years later, oops) adjust that first one's subquery to read `(select Parent_Id from A where Parent_Id is not null)`. Top-level items will have a null ParentId, and having nulls in the subquery's list will mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from a where id not in (select parent_id from table a)
```

In other words, select everything from table a where the ID of the item is not the parent ID of any other item.  This will give you all the leaf nodes of the graph.

EDIT:
Your edit is a bit confusing, and ID's aren't typically used as ordering mechanisms, but regardless, the example you give can be accomplished by this query

```
SELECT MAX( id )
FROM a
WHERE id NOT IN
  (SELECT parent_id
      FROM a
      WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
  )
GROUP BY parent_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the query a little to get only child categories, for Postgres 9.4

```
select count(id) from A as outer_ref where not exists(
    select 1 from A where parent_id=outer_ref.id) and parent_id is not null;
```